# i keeping getting the error SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle

Trying to do group by seem to keep getting this error can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
     SELECT 
           ACTIVITY_ID,
           ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION,
           Name,
           DESCRIPTION,
           PROJECT_NAME AS PROJECT
     FROM
            TASK_ACTIVITY
     INNER JOIN
           VOLUNTEER ON VOLUNTEER.VOLUNTEER_ID = TASK_ACTIVITY.VOLUNTEER_ID
     INNER JOIN
            TASK ON TASK.TASK_ID = TASK_ACTIVITY.TASK_ID
     INNER JOIN
            PROJECT ON PROJECT.PROJECT_ID = TASK.PROJECT_ID
     GROUP BY NAME, DESCRIPTION, ACTIVITY_ID, PROJECT NAME, 
             ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION.TASK_ACTIVITY
     ORDER BY NAME;

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: You're using Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: is `Name` and `NAME` same?. I mean upper and lower case

Comment: yes they belong to the volunteer table

Comment: There are lots of other oracle questions about this error message. Have you looked through them to see if any explain your problem?

Comment: You should try to use alias to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION` is a field but your are using like was a table

```
ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION.TASK_ACTIVITY
```

Probably you need a `,` to group by `TASK_ACTIVITY` but `TASK_ACTIVITY` is also a Table so not sure what you try to do

Comment: `TASK_ACTIVITY` appears to be a table name, so maybe it should be `TASK_ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION`.